# Back button doesn't show in React Navigation 6.x with nested navigators

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

My React Native app has a root Stack Navigator with some screens and nested navigators:

```js
/* Root Stack Navigator */
const disableBackButtonOpts = {
  headerBackVisible: false,
  gestureEnabled: false
}

<Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={Routes.MainTab}
    screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route, t),
        headerShown: false
    })}
>
    {/* Screens handling authentication and registration phases */}
    <Stack.Group screenOptions={{headerShown: true, ...disableBackButtonOpts}}>
        <Stack.Screen component={Authentication} name={Routes.Auth} />
        <Stack.Screen component={UserDataRegistration} name={Routes.UserData} />
        {/* 3 more screens ... */}
    </Stack.Group>

    {/* Application screens nested in BottomTab and Stack navigators */}
    <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen component={MainTabNavigator} name={Routes.MainTab} />
        <Stack.Screen component={PersonalAreaStackNavigator} name={Routes.Profile} />
        {/* Home, Messages and Documents stack screens */}
    </Stack.Group>
    {/* Others */}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

What I want to achieve is that the Tab Navigator displays 4 screens belonging to 4 stack navigators and, when navigating to different screens of these stack navigators, hide the tab bar.

Therefore I declared the Tab Navigator as follows:

```js
const screenOptions: (route: any) => BottomTabNavigationOptions = ({route}) => ({
  headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route, t),
  headerShown: true,
  tabBarActiveTintColor: style.activecolor,
  tabBarInactiveTintColor: style.inactivecolor,
  tabBarLabelStyle: style.tabBarLabel,
  tabBarStyle: style.tabBar
})

<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
  <Tab.Screen
    component={PersonalArea} name={Routes.PersonalArea}
  />
  {/* 3 more tab screens */}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

With `PersonalArea` component that is the initial screen of `PersonalAreaStackNavigator`, inside the root stack navigator:

```js
/* PersonalAreaStackNavigator */
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={({route}) => ({
    headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route, t),
    headerShown: true,
    headerBackButtonMenuEnabled: true,
    headerBackTitleVisible: true
  })}
>
  <Stack.Screen component={PersonalArea} name={Routes.PersonalArea} />
  <Stack.Screen component={PersonalData} name={Routes.PersonalData} />
  <Stack.Screen component={ScreenC} name={Routes.ScreenC} />
  <Stack.Screen component={ScreenD} name={Routes.} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

So, in this way, I have a structure as follows:

```
RootStack
|--Authentication Page
|--Registration Page
|--TabNavigator
|   |--PersonalArea
|   |--Screen B
|   |--Screen C
|   |--Screen D
|--PersonalAreaStack
|   |--PersonalArea
|   |--PersonalData
|   |--Screen E
|   |-- ...
|--ScreenBStack
|   |--Screen B
|   |-- ...
|  ScreenCStack
|   |--Screen C
|   |-- ...
|-- ...
```

Following the React Navigation [guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/) I was able to navigate between screens of the hiding the tab bar, but my **problem** here is that **the back button is not displayed** when navigating from one of the screens of the tab navigator to a stack navigator screen. For example, the path `TabNavigator -> PersonalArea -> PersonalData` doesn't show the back button in PersonalData screen, but `TabNavigator -> PersonalArea -> PersonalData -> Screen E` does (pointing to PersonalData screen).

This happens only on iOS.

How can I make the back button appear also in the first screen of the stack navigator to point to its first page included also in the tab bar?

Comment: Found a solution using styling settings: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#the-tabbarvisible-option-is-no-longer-present

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you got the back button to show? I don't understand how it's related to the tabBarVisible option.